# liquibase updateSQL

Tags: maven-plugin, liquibase

```
Hibernate Core: 3.5.6
DB: Oracle 11g
```

I am using the updateSQL goal to generate alter scripts (SQL files).

The resulting SQL files do not have the schema name (username) prepended. Is there any way this can be achieved?

A create table changeSet will result in

```
CREATE TABLE FOO ...
```

What I want is

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ.FOO ... where XYZ is the default schema name.
```

I have tried adding defaultSchemaName in the generate-resources

Would appreciate if I can get some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used liquibase-maven-plugin 2.0.2 and that resolved it. I was using 2.0.1 earlier.